# C# SMTP virtual server doesn't send mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

C# SMTP virtual server doesn't send mail. Here's the code:

```
public static void SendEmail(string _FromEmail, string _ToEmail, string _Subject, string _EmailBody)
{

    // setup email header . 
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "127.0.0.1";
    MailMessage _MailMessage = new MailMessage();

    _MailMessage.From = _FromEmail;
    _MailMessage.To = _ToEmail;
    _MailMessage.Subject = _Subject;
    _MailMessage.Body = _EmailBody;

    try
    {
        SmtpMail.Send(_MailMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            String str = ex.InnerException.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have got the following Exception :I have got the following Exception : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004020F): The server rejected one or more recipient addresses. The server response was: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for ragaei.mahmoud@invensys.com

Comment: --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters) at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams) at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags

Comment: On Access>relay of the Virtual Smpt server properities i checked "All Except the list below " and leave this list empty

Comment: I just try to send only one word "TEST"

Comment: Did you Grant 127.0.0.1 to the Computers list ?

Comment: Are you sure that 127.0.0.1 points to a valid SMTP server?  Also you are not setting the port (I assume you are using port forwarding?)

Comment: now the mail send but it is still inside :C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Queue

Comment: i am using default virtual server port 25 but i am inside a company and on my PC there is Mcafee ummm do yoiu think that mcafee block these mails from sending?i tried to figure out mcafee service but i can't coz it managed bu IT guy(i.e. all settings are gray and i can't chang any thing more)

Comment: all mails stuck in C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Queue

Answer (score 1):

It is an Interop exception because that .NET code is relying on Interop(erability) services, non-managed stuff. The message however is pretty clear, the server is unable to relay because it has been configured to reject relaying of emails.

Many years ago that was not a problem and you could virtually use any public SMTP server to send emails. With the advent of SPAM the whole game changed, now in most servers relaying is disabled and your mail send request is rejected.

What you will need here so that it does not reject your mail, is to authenticate your request (account/user and password on that server). It has to be a valid username & password combination known to that SMTP server. You do that by setting those (out of my head sorry) in the .Credentials property. See also the UseDefaultCredentials property, if you set Credentials you need to make sure UseDefaultCredentials is false.

Comment: now the mail send but it is still inside :C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Queue

Comment: from where exactly could I fetch UseDefaultCredentials ??

Answer (score 0):

If the error is this:

550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for ragaei.mahmoud@invensys.com

Then your SMTP server cannot send to that email address.  Use a different SMTP server or configure it to relay out to the internet.  The local one will probably only send to addresses on your own domain.  If this is an SMTP server configuration question, you may have more luck asking on Superuser.